# Is this basic fact about prime pairs obvious?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

$A_p = \{\text{prime } q: p + 2k = q \text{ for some } k \in \Bbb{Z}\}$ is the same set for any prime $p \geq 3$.

Is this obvious?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Notice that all primes $p\ge3$ are all odd.

Comment: Please turn your comments into answers if you think you have one.

Comment: I think the question isn't clear.  As it stands, the answer is obviously yes since the difference between any two odd numbers is even.  In particular, this has nothing to do with "prime pairs".

Comment: @lulu please explain in an answer if you dare.

Comment: Yes. This is obvious.

Comment: @lulu: The question is about the relationship between the sets $A_p$ and $A_q$ when $p, q$ is a pair of prime numbers.  That's what the "prime pair" in the title refers to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is indeed obvious. If $p\geq3$ is prime, then it is odd, so for any other prime number $q\neq2$ the difference $p-q$ is even, i.e. there is some $k\in\mathbb Z$ such that $p-q=2k$, hence $p-2k=q$, showing $q\in A_p$. Consequently, $A_p$ is the set of all odd primes for each prime $p\geq 3$.

Comment: And as mentioned in a comment above, this has nothing to do with prime pairs....

Answer (score 3):

If $p$ is an odd prime then $A_p$ is simply the set of all odd primes, because if $q$ is an odd prime then $q - p$ is even so $q - p = 2k$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$.